# Jquery Ajax Thumbs gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, gallery

I have been searching on google for days... and well I didn't find anything.

I'm also not sure if stack overflow is the right place to ask my question, anyway...

Anyone know a good jQuery Gallery plugins with reloading the image list with ajax and with images categories?

Thank you =D

Comment: Could you give us a little more about what you are trying to do?  Maybe a site you are trying to improve, or libraries that you've looked at and why you rejected them?  There are a lot of gallery plugins out there.

Comment: Well, anything similar to this, but using Ajax Request to reload the image list would be perfect. I pretty much googled and rejected everything that came in the 5 first pages containing the words "jquery, ajax, gallery, portofolio, php" in differents orders.

http://codecanyon.net/item/tonic-gallery-jquery-xml-portfolio-gallery/full_screen_preview/120710

Comment: You could use jquery tabs to hold the image categories, you can load tabs from separate pages via ajax. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/   On the separate pages, you could just have a simple lightbox script. JqueryUI tabs is really powerful and simple, you can restyle the entire mess.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are plugins then you can check these.

http://www.queness.com/post/222/10-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Well i love the MultimediaGallery.
In a  xml file you can define the thumbs and images, this way page load is faster. I've implemented it in asp.net but i don't use a xml file...well you need it for php and the original is for php:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/24/multimedia-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

Its better you use any static plugin and modify for getting your images dynamically.